# find_all_by in <select> table for a certain field in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a function where I want to show the corresponding value in a select form based on the function below :

```
 def index
    @initval = Haus.find_all_by_haus_id(1)
  end
```

It will return a list of value that has haus_id = "1" (so e.g. I will get a, b, c)

in index.rhtml, I want to show the list corresponding to haus_id="1", but showing only their timebuild (so e.g, I will get time of "a" was built, "b" was built, and "c" was built).

```
<select id="subtable" name="subtable" size="7" style="width: 150px">
    <option selected value="<%= @initval.id %>"><%= @initval.timebuild%></option>
</select>
```

However, it returns

```
undefined method `timebuild' for #<Array:0x4b5c238>
```

If in select form I change @initval.timebuild to @initival.id , it will return a number (that I am not sure where it came from). 
How can I show a list of timebuild from haus that has haus_id="1" in the select form?

Please kindly guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `find_all_by_haus_id` the result will be an array of all the matching `Haus` objects. Even if there is only one matching record it will still be an array with 1 element.

Every object in Ruby has an `id` method that returns the object's internal ID (although this method name is now deprecated in favour of `object_id`.) This is the number you are seeing when you call `id` on your array e.g.

```
irb(main):002:0> [1, 2, 3].id
(irb):2: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
=> 23959200
```

If you just want to return a single record you can use `Haus.find_by_haus_id`.

If you do want multiple values then stick with `find_all_by_haus_id` and use something like [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) to produce an `options` tag for each entry.

Finally, if `haus_id` is the primary key in your table then you can just use `find` to return the matching object e.g.

```
@initval = Haus.find(1)
```